# Data structure alignment: why are array of char and std::string different

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

Known that `sizeof(std::string)` is 8, `sizeof(int)` is 4.

```
class Test1
{
int i;            // 4
std::string str;  // 8
};
```

`sizeof(Test1)` is 16, because 8 = N1 * 4 and 16 = N2 * 8. (N1 and N2 are natural numbers)

However, if I replace `std::string` with `char [8]` as below:

```
class Test2
{
int i;       // 4
char ch[8];  // 8
};
```

I don't know why `sizeof(Test2)` gives me 12.

Comment: `string` has 8-byte alignment but `char` has 1-byte alignment (even if array of char)

Comment: Which compiler/version? Do you compile as 64-bit?

Comment: search for structure padding and alignment requirements.

Comment: Which system gives you `sizeof(std::string)` as 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 + 8 = 12, so 12 bytes is the minimum amount of memory to fit a 4 and a 8 byte object.

However, there is another consideration besides the total number of bytes of the subobjects. Each subobject has a particular alignment requirement.

The alignment of `std::string` depends on its complete subobjects, which are implementation defined. It appears, that `std::string` on your implementation has to be aligned to an 8 byte boundary. As a consequence, the alignment requirement of `Test1` is also 8, and there must be 4 bytes of padding after the member `i`. So, the size of `Test1` is the sum of the sizes of the subobjects + the pad bytes, which totals 4 + 8 + 4 = 16.

`char` and consequently `char[8]` have alignment requirement of 1. Therefore the alignment requirement of `Test2` is `4` (because of `int` member) and no padding is required after the member `i`. Since there is no padding, the size of `Test2` matches the sum of the sizes of the subobjects.

---

Another point of view is that the size must be a multiple of the alignment requirement. 16 is the smallest multiple of 8 (alignment of `Test1`) that is greater than or equal to 12. 12 is the smallest multiple of 4 (alignment of `Test2`) that is greater than or equal to 12.

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of `char` is 1, and this holds for arrays of characters too. So no padding is added between the class members. Thus you get the size as `4 + 8 = 12`.